# Exporting cloudwatch logs results in limitExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We are using step functions to periodically aggregate logs and forward logs to s3 buucket using lambda, limitExceededException is coming from Forward Logs Lambda and this happens randomly not all the time.

Since I haven't written code for this implementation so posting a reproducible example would be difficult.

Upon my investigation, I found out that this error is mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateExportTask.html `where Each account can only have one active (RUNNING or PENDING) export task at a time.`

lambda code

```
async invokeForwardingTask(
    options: ForwardingTaskInvokingOptions
  ): Promise<void> {
    const { from, logGroupName, to } = options
    const date = dayjs.utc(from)
    const partitionPrefix = [
      `year=${date.format('YYYY')}`,
      `month=${date.format('MM')}`,
      `day=${date.format('DD')}`,
    ].join('/')
    const categoryPrefix = logGroupName.replace(/^\//, '')


    await this.cwl
      .createExportTask({
        logGroupName,
        destination: this.logDestination,
        from,
        to,
        destinationPrefix: `${categoryPrefix}/${partitionPrefix}`,
      })
      .promise()
```

step functions code

```
const logForwarding = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, 'Forward a log', {
      lambdaFunction: forwarder.lambdaFunction,
      inputPath: '$.systemLog',
      outputPath: '$.Payload',
      timeout: Duration.seconds(
        logForwardingRetryConfig.interval.toSeconds() +
          logForwardingRetryConfig.interval.toSeconds() *
            logForwardingRetryConfig.backOffRate *
            (logForwardingRetryConfig.maxAttempts - 1)
      ),
    })

    const oneMinWaiting = new sfn.Wait(this, 'Wait for a while', {
      time: sfn.WaitTime.duration(Duration.minutes(2)),
    })

    const choice = new sfn.Choice(this, 'No Logs?')
      .when(
        sfn.Condition.numberEquals('$.systemLog.length', 0),
        new sfn.Succeed(this, 'No more logs')
      )
      .otherwise(logForwarding)
    const definition = logAggregation.next(choice)
    choice.afterwards().next(oneMinWaiting).next(choice)
    logForwarding.addRetry(logForwardingRetryConfig)

    const stateMachine = new StepFunctions(this, 'StepFunctions', {
      definition,
    })

    // Every 1 AM in JST
    stateMachine.addEventsRule('cron(0 16 * * ? *)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely being throttled from Cloudwatch logs on that particular API. Try checking your cloudwatch metrics to see whether you need to increase your service level limits

Comment: I couldn't see any of thee metric going beyond service level limits, even checked the  service quotas but found nothing

Comment: In that case I would open a support ticket with Cloudwatch team to verify the cause of the limitExceededException. Sending them the request IDs that are failing sporadically would help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).